# Table at the beginning of itemize environment

Tags: tables, spacing, itemize

Inserting a table at the beginning of an itemize environment creates an unwanted spacing. How do i prevent this?

```
\begin{frame}
\footnotesize
\textbf{Aufgabe:\hspace{3mm}Zweidimensionale diskrete    
 Zufallsvariablen}\\[3mm]
  \begin{itemize}
\item[a)] \begin{table}[H]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \begin{tabular}{|C{1.5cm}||C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}||C{1.5cm}|} \hline
         $X \ \textbackslash \ Y$  & $y_1=0$  & $y_2=1$ & $y_3=2$ & $f_X(x_i)$      \\ \hline\hline 
         $x_1=2$               & (1)      & $0,08$  & $0,04$  & $0,4$      \\ \hline    
         $x_2=4$               & $0,14$   & (7)     & (3)     & $0,2$   \\  \hline  
         $x_3=6$               & (2)      & (5)     & $0,04$  & (4)   \\    \hline\hline    
         $f_Y(y_j)$            & $0,7$    & (6)     & $0,1$   & $1$   \\    \hline  
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
  \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What spacing?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use a `table` environment when you want to set a `tabular`. So, set it as-is, without the use of `\centering`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \footnotesize
  \textbf{Aufgabe:\hspace{3mm}Zweidimensionale diskrete    
  Zufallsvariablen}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item[a)]
      \begin{tabular}{|C{1.5cm}||C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}||C{1.5cm}|} \hline
        $X \setminus Y$  & $y_1=0$  & $y_2=1$ & $y_3=2$ & $f_X(x_i)$ \\ \hline\hline
        $x_1=2$          & (1)      & $0,08$  & $0,04$  & $0,4$      \\ \hline
        $x_2=4$          & $0,14$   & (7)     & (3)     & $0,2$      \\ \hline
        $x_3=6$          & (2)      & (5)     & $0,04$  & (4)        \\ \hline\hline
        $f_Y(y_j)$       & $0,7$    & (6)     & $0,1$   & $1$        \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}

    \item[b)]
      \begin{tabular}{ C{1.5cm} *{3}{C{1cm}} C{1.5cm} }
        \toprule
        $X \setminus Y$  & $y_1=0$  & $y_2=1$ & $y_3=2$ & $f_X(x_i)$ \\
        \midrule
        $x_1=2$          & (1)      & $0.08$  & $0.04$  & $0.4$      \\
        $x_2=4$          & $0.14$   & (7)     & (3)     & $0.2$      \\
        $x_3=6$          & (2)      & (5)     & $0.04$  & (4)        \\
        \bottomrule
        $f_Y(y_j)$       & $0.7\phantom{0}$    & (6)     & $0.1\phantom{0}$   & $1$        \\
      \end{tabular}

  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I've suggested some alternatives to your `tabular` in my `\item[b)]` using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), for example.

---

Vertical alignment of the `\item` with the `tabular`s could be achieved using some raising:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \footnotesize
  \textbf{Aufgabe:\hspace{3mm}Zweidimensionale diskrete    
  Zufallsvariablen}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item[a)]
      \raisebox{\dimexpr.7\baselineskip+.4pt}{\begin{tabular}[t]{|C{1.5cm}||C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}||C{1.5cm}|} \hline
        $X \setminus Y$  & $y_1=0$  & $y_2=1$ & $y_3=2$ & $f_X(x_i)$ \\ \hline\hline
        $x_1=2$          & (1)      & $0,08$  & $0,04$  & $0,4$      \\ \hline
        $x_2=4$          & $0,14$   & (7)     & (3)     & $0,2$      \\ \hline
        $x_3=6$          & (2)      & (5)     & $0,04$  & (4)        \\ \hline\hline
        $f_Y(y_j)$       & $0,7$    & (6)     & $0,1$   & $1$        \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}}

    \item[b)]
      \raisebox{\dimexpr\aboverulesep+\heavyrulewidth+\belowrulesep+.5\baselineskip}{\begin{tabular}[t]{ C{1.5cm} *{3}{C{1cm}} C{1.5cm} }
        \toprule
        $X \setminus Y$  & $y_1=0$  & $y_2=1$ & $y_3=2$ & $f_X(x_i)$ \\
        \midrule
        $x_1=2$          & (1)      & $0.08$  & $0.04$  & $0.4$      \\
        $x_2=4$          & $0.14$   & (7)     & (3)     & $0.2$      \\
        $x_3=6$          & (2)      & (5)     & $0.04$  & (4)        \\
        \bottomrule
        $f_Y(y_j)$       & $0.7\phantom{0}$    & (6)     & $0.1\phantom{0}$   & $1$        \\
      \end{tabular}}

  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? I raised the table by `\arraystretch × 0.7\baselineskip` (the height of a row in the table above the baseline). I slightly improved the look of tthe table using `hhline`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array, hhline}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\footnotesize
\textbf{Aufgabe:\hspace{3mm}Zweidimensionale diskrete
 Zufallsvariablen}\\[3mm]
  \begin{itemize}
\item[a)]\raisebox{0.91\baselineskip}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|C{1.5cm}||C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}||C{1.5cm}|}
         \hhline{-||---||-} 
         $X \ \textbackslash \ Y$ & $y_1=0$ & $y_2=1$ & $y_3=2$ & $f_X(x_i)$ \\ 
         \hhline{:=::===::=:}
         $x_1=2$ & (1) & $0,08$ & $0,04$ & $0,4$ \\ 
         \hhline{-||---||-}
         $x_2=4$ & $0,14$ & (7) & (3) & $0,2$ \\
         \hhline{-||---||-}
         $x_3=6$ & (2) & (5) & $0,04$ & (4) \\
         \hhline{:=::===::=:}
         $f_Y(y_j)$ & $0,7$ & (6) & $0,1$ & $1$ \\
         \hhline{-||---||-} 
    \end{tabular}}
  \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}

  \end{document}
```

[image]